# C#: square bracket alternative / a class for multiple SOAP addresses

Tags: c#

I've generated a SOAP class using `wsdl.exe` tool. Unfortunately, it seems to be bound to a specific URL and I need to be able to change it on per-instance basis (I'd like to be able to connect to multiple URLs that share the same interface). So, I'd like to change such code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="Service1Soap", Namespace="http://productmarket.bigbrain.math.uni.lodz.pl/")]
public partial class Service1 : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

// some code here

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://productmarket.bigbrain.math.uni.lodz.pl/Authenticate", RequestNamespace="http://productmarket.bigbrain.math.uni.lodz.pl/", ResponseNamespace="http://productmarket.bigbrain.math.uni.lodz.pl/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public bool Authenticate(int ContractorId, string Password) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("Authenticate", new object[] {
                    ContractorId,
                    Password});
        return ((bool)(results[0]));
    }

// more code here

}
```

So that the attributes from Authenticate (the ones with HTTP URL's) are variable. The only solution I've found so far is to make a static string inside of Service1 class and change the Authenticate code like that:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="Service1Soap", Namespace="http://productmarket.bigbrain.math.uni.lodz.pl/")]
public partial class Service1 : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {


//some code

    public static string prefix = "http://productmarket.bigbrain.math.uni.lodz.pl/";
    public static string soap_namespace = "http://productmarket.bigbrain.math.uni.lodz.pl/";


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(Service1.prefix+"Authenticate", RequestNamespace=Service1.soap_namespace, ResponseNamespace=Service1.soap_namespace, Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public bool Authenticate(int ContractorId, string Password) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("Authenticate", new object[] {
                    ContractorId,
                    Password});
        return ((bool)(results[0]));
    }

//some code

}
```

Is there a better solution that would pull this info from instances instead of forcing me to change them every request? I must admit I don't exactly understand the concept of attributes in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace attributes aren't the service endpoint. The purpose is to define exactly a namespace, or bettere the [xml namespace](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml%20namespace) of the entities/methods used in soap call.

The url endpoint of the server part is implicit defined where the service is published.

In the client part depend on the specific implementation.

For the wsdl.exe client as I remember the syntax is somethings like that:

```
Service1 ws = new Service1();
ws.Url = "http://anyserver.addr/of/the/service.asmx";

bool auth = ws.Authenticate(21,"****");
```

Comment: There wasn't the edited part then. Though, with .Url changing, we don't change the parameters before the attribute syntax. The namespaces and the method URL's.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, but the namespace and prefix shouldn't change unless the wsdl (so the service signature) changes. If the same service (server code) is published in a different url, the  xml namespace normally is the same.

Comment: Yeah, they shouldn't, unless I'd like to use multiple instances of the same class, each having it's own namespace and prefix. I'd like to connect to multiple web services, all share the same interface, but are on different websites.

Comment: Multiple web services instances (different urls) of the same service (same WSDL) have the same prefix (namespace is hardcoded in the WSDL). Unless your different server instances have different WSDL, in this case I don't know if there is a solution with wsdl.exe's generated files.

Comment: The WSDL doesn't have to be the same. Method names and parameters have to be.