# ASP.net - connect to multiple Web Services from different URL's/host that share the same interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'd like my ASP.NET application to be able to talk to any number of different hosts, all providing a Web Service that has exactly the same interface, but on different domains/ASMX URL's. I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482773/web-service-without-adding-a-reference) a solution that allows me to generate a class for one web service, but the URL address/prefix/namespaces are hardcoded in the method attributes and I don't know how to change them (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523135/c-curly-bracket-alternative-a-class-for-multiple-soap-addresses)). Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is using DynWsib - [HERE](http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/tools-and-software/dynwslib). Please note this does not work with WCF.

You can then invoke at runtime. Binaries are created and cached for each url. Function below is basic idea. Change as needed.

```
public object InvokeWebserviceCall(string wsdUrl, string actionUrl, string functionName,
        string domain, string username, string password, params object[] parameters)
    {
        ///todo: validate input

        var proxy = new DynamicWebServiceProxy();

        //credentials if needed
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
        {
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        }

        proxy.EnableMessageAccess = true;
        proxy.Wsdl = wsdUrl;

        //get type name
        var type = proxy.ProxyAssembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.BaseType == typeof(SoapHttpClientProtocolExtended));

        if (type != null)
        {
            proxy.TypeName = type.Name;
        }

        proxy.MethodName = functionName;
        proxy.Url = new Uri(actionUrl);

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            parameters.ToList().ForEach(proxy.AddParameter);
        }

        object result = proxy.InvokeCall();

        return result;
    }
```